# Managing windows overlapping: docking a window on the desktop

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, desktop, window-manager

I'm looking for a way to manage the windows overlapping. In particular, I'd like to reach this goal: given more than 1 window (e.g. Chrome, Excel), I want to dock the Excel window on a part of the desktop, but, if I click on Chrome, this window should overlap all other opened windows (as usual in normal Windows 10).

Answer (score 0):

There is no Windows setting or native automation to do what you want. I have not seen third party apps for this either. In particular, you cannot "dock" a windows in Windows. It can always be moved / re-sized.

You have to size and then set up your Windows manually. I have Virtual machines in a window and Edge overlaps that setup.

So setting it up as you wish does work quite well.

Comment: Hello @John, thank you for your reply. If possible I'd like to avoid to use virtual machines

Comment: My answer was how to setup windows and virtual machines windows is just an example - nothing more than that. So no need to use virtual machines for what I am suggesting.

Comment: Sorry @John I didn't get how to dock a window on te desktop and to allow to another window to overlap it. After I chose the size, what I should do?

Comment: I have a window on my screen in a particular location. I run another app, some overlap and some do not. But that does not change the position of the existing window. It is how I manage windows. You cannot "dock" a window on the screen. It is all manual and I set things up quite particularly .